# Remove routeparam from controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

How clear `routeparam` in `angularjs` from controller.

I am using `routeparam` for updating a task,in popup.

```
url :- http://invoice.local/#/expenses/9
```

When route param exist,I open model box with form to update expense details,After successful update,I want to clear `routeparam`. Otherwise model box opening again.

```
     /**
     *  Open expense details if expense id in route param
     */
    if ($routeParams.expenseId) {
        expenseService.get($routeParams.expenseId)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.expense = expenseService.updateDateFormat(data, false);
                    $('#ModelBox').modal('show');
                });

    }
```

saving,
refreshing current page,

```
$route.reload()
```

Here I want to clear routeparam and need to reload `http://invoice.local/#/expenses/`

Answer (score 2):

You can use $location for clearing parameters:

```
$location.search('expenseId', null)
```

but what you want is to change the path:

```
$location.path('/expenses')
```

This will load the expenses page, removing expenseId parameter and you can skip`$route.reload()`, it will reload the page.